# Mouse stops working on resolution change

Tags: mouse, display, display-resolution

I'm working on some very old laptop at the moment that will die pretty soon... Anyway, today it crashed (overheated) and after boot the resolution changed from default 1280x800 to 1024x768.

I thought it wasn't big problem so I just opened the terminal and checked `xrandr -q`. Here's what I got:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
LVDS connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800      59.98 +
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95* 
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Obviously the resolution I worry about is `LVDS` (VGA cable is not connected). So I have run `xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1280x800` command. The resolution changed as expected but new problem occurred with my mouse.

The pointer is displayed and moves but clicks don't anything - just like there were some invisible layer above everything. I even tried to connect a TV with VGA cable to check if there's some window on non existing screen but no.

What could be the reason?

[edit] I am running pretty standard Lubuntu distribution and I upgraded the kernel this morning... could it be connected somehow?

Comment: any updates on the question?